# Can't use JSPrintManager in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I try use JSPrintManager in reactjs app. I just added model using npm then import it import JSPM from 'jsprintmanager' but when I call JSPM.JSPrintManager I get this error

here the code

import JSPM from 'jsprintmanager'
componentDidMount() {

```
    JSPM.JSPrintManager.auto_reconnect = true;
    JSPM.JSPrintManager.start();

}
```

here the error
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this import:

I used `"jsprintmanager": "^4.0.7"`

```
import { JSPrintManager, WSStatus, ClientScanJob, ScannerImageFormatOutput } from 'jsprintmanager';
```

and now you can use

```
JSPrintManager.auto_reconnect = true;
JSPrintManager.start();
```

Not use JSPM

Answer (score 0):

It is also important to mention that you need to have actual client app installed. It won't work without it and you will get a runtime error, especially if you use code from their demo example.